# What GSM module I should use for HttpClient, ArduinoHttpClient, WebSockets etc.?

Tags: gsm, http

I need to use some API in my project. So I'm gonna use such libraries as listed in the title? What GSM/SIM module do I need for this purpose? I've checked 800L and similar - it only can use plain http, and only via AT command. At least based on this, that's not what I really need. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The TinyGSM library implements the Arduino Client class required by networking super libraries you mention in the question.

TinyGSM [supports](https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM#supported-modems) the SIM800 modems.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what about http only, no https?

Comment: @picKit, see the "SSL/TLS (HTTPS)" paragraph in README